# Magento 1.8 - Cant access frontend - Access Forbidden - 403 Status Code

Tags: magento-1.8, frontend, access

I can't access my magento frontend. I get:

> **Access forbidden!** You don't have permission to access the requested
>   object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

Backend works.
I executed this inside the project folder to fix the permissions:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 644
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 755
```

But that was not changing anything. I also deleted the cache after it.

I also tried:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 777
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 777
```

...temporarily. No difference...

I also deleted my .htaccess file and tried it again. But still **Access forbidden!**

Im not sure what is going on?

Comment: Did you added any extension or any custom code?

Comment: Not recently. I just executed git pull on a old project.

Comment: Can you check permissions to your project? I mean file permissions.

Comment: Seems to be correct

Comment: Are you using xampp?

Comment: Im not sure, the server is hosted externally.

Comment: Can you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17816732/xampp-access-forbidden-php

Comment: I can't. I dont have access to the virtual host config.

Comment: Can you try if other projects are working fine there?

Comment: Yes other projects work fine.

Comment: @SukumarGorai, I was able to solve it. An extension was causing this.

Comment: Great! accept your answer.

Comment: I can only accept the answer in two days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! After disabling extension after extension I found out, that the extension **GeoIP Extension**, from **Mageworx** was causing the access denied error.

The Extension needed write permission to the folder **media/mageworx/geoip** but the folder was not existing and thus causing the error.

So the GeoIP Extension just blocked every IP.